# String of Binary Values to Binary File

Tags: swift, binary, binaryfiles

I have a large string (~600 bytes) of binary bits that I need to save into a binary file.

If I just save the string to a file using `String.write` then the 1's and 0's will be encoded as their Unicode/ASCII values.

I need it so that if I opened the file with `xxd -b` for example it would output the same binary bits as I currently have in the string.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you use a *string* (of "0" and "1" characters) for the bits, and not a more appropriate data structure, like `Data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string with a series of “0” and “1” characters, and want a binary representation, you can do:

```
extension String {
    var binaryData: Data {
        let values = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[01]{8}")
            .matches(in: self, range: NSRange(startIndex..., in: self))
            .compactMap { Range($0.range, in: self) }
            .compactMap { self[$0] }
            .compactMap { UInt8($0, radix: 2) }
        return Data(values)
    }
}
```

Thus

```
let input = "010000010100001001000011"
let data = input.binaryData               // 0x41 0x42 0x43
```

You can then write that `Data` to a file, or do whatever you want with it.